# To use -c0 -i0 in file-systems with journal

Tags: filesystems, ext4, journaling

I've several partitions with `ext4`.
Now, I would want if it makes sense to use `tune2fs` with flags `-c0` (`max-mount-counts`) and `-i0` (`interval-between-checks`) in the partitions with a journal file-system since it needs less checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking... [yes, it does make sense](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/43378/).
Though you might want to run

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdXY | egrep "Maxim|Check"
```

to see how those flags are set as it all depends on the version of `e2fsprogs` used to create the filesystems and/or distribution specific patches applied to `e2fsprogs`. You might already have `MAX_MNT_COUNT` and `CHECKINTERVAL` set to `-1` and `0` respectively, due to the fact that, as of v. 1.42, `e2fsprogs` defaults to `-c1 -i0`, see [changelog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/files/e2fsprogs/1.42/):

> If the enable_periodic_fsck option is false in /etc/mke2fs.conf (which
>   is the default), mke2fs will now set the s_max_mnt_count superblock
>   field to -1, instead of 0. Kernels older then 3.0 will print a
>   spurious message on each mount then they see a s_max_mnt_count set to
>   0, which will annoy users.

`/etc/mke2fs.conf` compared:

v. 1.41.14 released 2010-12-22:

```
[defaults]
    base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
    blocksize = 4096
    inode_size = 256
    inode_ratio = 16384
```

v. 1.42 released 2011-11-29:

```
[defaults]
    base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
    default_mntopts = acl,user_xattr
    enable_periodic_fsck = 0
    blocksize = 4096
    inode_size = 256
    inode_ratio = 16384
```