# Linux fsck while boot

Tags: fsck

If the file systems are meant to do fsck while booting, why is Linux not able to do fsck sometimes, and going into maintenance mode?

Comment: This question is meaningless without specifying the operating system, which it does not specify.  (Linux is not an operating system.)  Because only by knowing the operating system will one know whether the premise of the question is even true in the first place.  What happens upon fsck failure is highly dependant from the operating system's choice of system management, and for some choices this premise is _false_.

Comment: Could you possibly give a bit more context to your question, including what Linux you are using, what filesystem type you are using, and what errors `fsck` is encountering?

Comment: The `fsck`, or "disk check" operation should not be required in normal circumstances. If you're having it happen regularly there's something else at play - for example, perhaps you're pulling the power on your computer rather than shutting it down cleanly (from software).

Answer (score 0):

In general, a Linux system will run full fsck at boot-up for three reasons only:

1. the maximum mount count for the filesystem was reached (an fsck resets it)
2. the fs was not unmounted cleanly (system crash, power failure, hard power reset, etc), so the "clean" flag was not set for the filesystem.
3. you specifically told it to.

If the fsck drops you into maintenance mode, it was probably for a good reason; the filesystem was in a state that was deemed to be beyond automatic repair.

If this happens often, then you have something wrong with the system. Without extremely detailed data, it's impossible to tell if the problem lies with the physical disk itself, the connectors, the disk driver, the user, or something else entirely. User error (e.g. pulling the plug instead of waiting for a clean shutdown) is a very common cause, and should be the first thing to check.

Comment: It's worth remembering that `mke2fs` has not defaulted to setting a maximum mount count since 2011.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47884/5132  Also note that the _real_ set of reasons is not uniformly hardwired into the various underlying `fsck` tools.  `e2fsck`, for one, has more than those 3 scenarios.  It also looks for an exceeded check interval or mismatched superblock features, for starters.